# Textarea Character Limit, and Whitespace Trim

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble creating a code in javascript to limit characters in an input box and trim whitespace. I am asked to use document.getElementById(, onkeyup event handler, and String.split().

I could only do this:

```
<script>
TextareaElement(document.getElementById("myWordsToCount")); 

myTextareaElement.onkeyup = function(){
    var maxlimit = 20;
    var counter = maxlimit - information.value.split(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').length;

   }
</script>
```

I am so new to javascript and I am thinking it might not be my zone. Anyways, I would deeply appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For limiting length you should use maxlenght like

```
  input type="text" maxlength="20"
```

And for trim

```
 var a =document.getElemenyById("YourId").value;
 var str=a.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with Jquery instead of typical JavaScript.
You could do it like :

```
//Now Assuming your text area has an id of "#text"

var text = document.getElementById('#text').val();

var trim = $.trim(text);

var characters = 100;  //you could change the number of characters you want    

$("#counter").append("You have <strong>"+  characters+"</strong> characters remaining");

$("#text").keyup(function(){
if($(this).val().length > characters){
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characters));
}

var remaining = characters -  $(this).val().length;
$("#counter").html("You have <strong>"+  remaining+"</strong> characters remaining");
if(remaining <= 10)
{
    $("#counter").css("color","red");
}
else
{
    $("#counter").css("color","black");
}
```

You could also turn the above code into a function so that you could call this every time the user enter some text in the textbox.